# Jquery form validation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with multiple inputs and I need to validate them on a button click.
The problem I'm having is if there is more than one required field it seems call to `valid()` validates only the first. Other fields are omitted.

```js
$(function() {
  //simple example 1
  //click event for first button 
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#form1").valid(); //validate form 1
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
  Field 1: <input id="field1" type="text" class="required" />
  <br/>Field 2: <input id="field2" type="text" class="required" />
  <div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Associated [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrfhU/1526/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with the missing name fields and it works fine.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1">
    Field 1: <input id="field1" type="text" name="field1" class="required" />
      
    <br/>

    Field 2: <input id="field2" type="text" name="field2" class="required" />

    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate" />

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the name fields fixed the problem. Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Add input for all fields presents on form

```
 $("#form1 input").valid();
```